# Cakephp Localization

Tags: php, cakephp, localization

I'm wokring on localizing some pages in my website , so I have added these to links, in the header

```
 echo $this->Html->link('Eglish', array('language' => 'eng'));
 echo $this->Html->link('Español', array('language' => 'spa'));
```

this worked fine in the index , but in the view, it redirect me to the page without the id , how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

From what have read in cakephp api [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links), I believe you have not given the correct route/url for this action. You should make this an action of one of your controllers and then it will be accessible and working from everywhere.